# Install Octave Package Manually

Tags: installation, octave, package, local

I want to install the package `dataframe` of Octave on one of my servers, which does not have internet access. I used my laptop to download `dataframe-1.1.0.tar.gz`. I wonder how I can install it on my server manually.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html

Comment: The content of the link did mention about installing packages, but not manual installation.

Comment: @James the content of the link is about manual installation. It's very first sentence and it's first example is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the README.html of Octave 4.0.0 folder you can find the following passage:

`Included Octave Forge Packages
A number of Octave-Forge packages have been included with Octave, however they must be installed in order to use them. 
To install: 
•   Start Octave and then open the build_packages.m file found in the src folder where Octave was installed.
•   Run the script build_packages.m to build and install the packages.
Installation is a one-time procedure. After installation packages must still be loaded in order to use them with the pkg load PACKAGENAME command. 
Other packages are available from Octave-Forge.`

What you need to do for other packages, which are not included with Octave, is: download the package from http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php. Then put the package in the src folder and modify build_packages.m respectively before executing it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Octave documentation:

> **[37.1 Installing and Removing Packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html)**
>
> Assuming a package is available in the file image-1.0.0.tar.gz it can
>   be installed from the Octave prompt with the command
>
> ```
> pkg install image-1.0.0.tar.gz
> ```
>
> If the package is installed successfully nothing will be printed on
>   the prompt, but if an error occurred during installation it will be
>   reported. It is possible to install several packages at once by
>   writing several package files after the pkg install command. If a
>   different version of the package is already installed it will be
>   removed prior to installing the new package. This makes it easy to
>   upgrade and downgrade the version of a package, but makes it
>   impossible to have several versions of the same package installed at
>   once.

Comment: Would this work in Linux running on an Arm 64 bit processor?