# Installing a non forge package in Octave

Tags: octave

Trying to install a  package to do with dynalog analysis which is not on Octave Forge, and unless i have all the functions of the package the current directory my code will not work (i need to change the current directory in my code frequently so need to have it installed).

How would i go about installing this package - is there a way to manually input all the functions without having to shift all of them to the current directory all the time?

(i'm new to octave this may be really easy and simple)

(Using octave 4.2.1 and can't find the build_packages.m file in the src folder as suggested in this question [Install Octave Package Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504203/install-octave-package-manually))

package is this one

http://www.mike-hughes.org/dynalog-file-analysis-for-matlaboctave/

Comment: typically the package will include instructions and or helper scripts to set the paths. This should be your first point to look. Since you haven't included a link to the package we can't look for you

Comment: my bad added it now, can't find any installation instructions in the readme - what would you suggest

Comment: since it's only a buch auf .m scripts a `addpath(absolute_path)` should be sufficient